# WebClient downloads corrupted files

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to download a Graph.zip file from a certain URL : https://www.dropbox.com/s/erc6ke9k1x2nle0/Graph.zip
Using this code:

```cs
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("https://www.dropbox.com/s/erc6ke9k1x2nle0/Graph.zip",
                        @"Graph.zip");
```

Whenever I execute the code, its either corrupted and/or 0 bytes in size.
Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Try to open the url from your browser: https://www.dropbox.com/s/erc6ke9k1x2nle0/Graph.zip

You'll notice that you are redirected to an intermediary page. If you save it to a zip file extention, then since the file is not really zip, it appears as corrupted to zip clients. To download dropbox files, you either need to use the rest api, or the sdk.

Check the sample console application here for an example: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial

```
async Task Download(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string file)
{
    using (var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(folder + "/" + file))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(await response.GetContentAsStringAsync());
    }
}
```